# Add Contacts to Campaign as Campaign Members using batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I have a requirement where I need to add Contacts to a specific campaign record as campaign members when the status(Custom Field) of Contact is Closed Lost. I was stuck as adding contacts to campaign members. Can someone help me do this since I am new to salesforce...

```
global class AddContactsToCampaignBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name 
                                         FROM Campaign 
                                         WHERE Name = 'Pipeline Campaign']);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Campaign> scope) {
        List<CampaignMember>newMember = new List<CampaignMember>();
        for(Contact con : [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Contact]) {
            if(con.Status__c == 'Closed Lost') {
                CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember (CampaignId =scope.Id, ContactId = con.Id, Status = 'Sent'); 
            }
        }
        //update conList;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here.

First, scope is a list, so you need to iterate over the list of campaigns passed in:

```
for(Campaign campaignRecord: scope) {
```

Second, your query should filter by status instead of querying the entire database:

```
Contact[] contactRecords = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Status__c = 'Closed Lost'];
```

Third, it's much more likely that you'd want to iterate the other way around, that is, the contacts should be the target of the batch, as you'll quickly run into governor limits the way you've gone.

Fourth, you needed to add the CampaignMember records to the list `newMember`, and then insert those records when you're ready.

Here's the revised code with those changes:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Status__c = 'Closed Lost'
    ]);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Contact[] scope) {
    Campaign[] pipelineCampaigns = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name = 'Pipeline Campaign'];
    CampaignMember[] newMembers = new CampaignMember[0];
    for(Contact contactRecord: scope) {
        for(Campaign pipelineCampaign: pipelineCampaigns) {
            newMembers.add(new CamapignMember(
                CampaignId = pipelineCampaign.Id, 
                ContactId = contactRecord.Id, 
                Status = 'Sent'
            ));
        }
    }
    insert newMembers;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Thanks for your help It worked. But, I have a doubt in the code you have used nested for loop. Are we supposed to use like this...

Comment: @SaiVineeth The rule about not using nested loops has to do with unnecessary performance issues. Generally, we're told to not do this because we should use a Map instead, and this is true *almost* always. However, if your intent is to create a new record for every X and every Y, this is one of the few appropriate times to use a nested loop (the other being when the children are already made relevant somehow). Feel free to search this site for nested loop Q&A (or even ask a separate question) to learn the difference between when to use and not.